# Разница между private и public методами после компиляции?

Tags: c++

Какое будет отличие public и private методов в машинном коде после компиляции или это отличие только на уровне C++ кода?

Comment: Private методы не будут видны для экспорта, если это библиотека

Comment: Только на уровне С++ кода.

Comment: Почему бы Вам не посмотреть это самому?

Comment: @NewView: Это как это? А как же оно линковаться будет?

Comment: @Ant, разве приватные методы класса видны из библиотеки? И с чем они должны линковаться, когда это внутренние методы? Вроде по умолчанию делается .def где и запрещен экспорт, вернее от обратного, - разрешен экспорт

Comment: @NewView: Мне никто не запрещает определить public метод класса вне библиотеки. А этот метод имеет право вызывать private методы. Как он сможет их вызывать, если они не видны? (Вы вообще о какой "библиотеке" ведете речь? О динамической?)

Comment: Теоретически да, но для этого надо наследоваться от класса итд. Вроде это относится только к protected, virtual методам, к private в собранной библиотеки доступ запрещен, если я правильно помню..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ограничения доступа проверяются только на стадии компиляции на уровне языка, т.е. на уровне исходного С++ кода. В скомпилированном коде уже никакой разницы нет и никаких мер контроля доступа нет тоже.

Answer (score 1):

Ограничение доступа действует только законодательно, для контроля доступа к элементам классов. Меняются эти ограничения очень просто, как говорят "на бумаге" используя классы потомки.

```
class A {
public:
    int f(){return a;}
private:
  int a;
};

class B : private A {
public:
};

int m(int x){
    if(x){
        A a;
        return a.f();}
    else{
        B b ;
        return ((A&)b).f();} }
```

Объекты из класса **B** не имеют право лично использовать метод **f**. Но практически можно изменить тип указателя на предка. И никаких ограничений не будет. Код этого метода будет исполняться одинаково, будь это вызывал объект A или B.